# Block access to a specific pipeline in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-rbac

I have a pipeline named "Privacy Pipeline".

I would like to only one person to be able to access this pipeline "user@data.com"

Is it possible to apply RBAC IAM controls at this level?

I've tried creating a custom role in Access control in the data factory and in PowerShell but I've not been able to get this working. Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to restrict access to the pipeline? From what I can understand, all users with access to the Data Factory, can run all the pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

From the above image, the error message is self explanotry to solve the problem:

**Problem:** You are experiencing this issue due to you're currently signed in with a user that **doesn't have permission to assign roles** at the selected scope shown in the image.

**Solution:** You must be signed in as a user that is assigned a role such as `owner` or `user access administrator` at this scope to resolve the issue.

Below gif shows steps to see all available permissions and actions for Azure Data factory while creating custom role. Kindly try the same and go through permissions and actions there and take call which one to consider in your custom role:

[image]

For more details, refer to [Custom role to restrict Azure Data Factory pipeline developers to create/delete linked services](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/custom-role-to-restrict-azure-data-factory-pipeline-developers/ba-p/3299161).